# JavaScript Topdown Collision Detection, working out axis that has been collided with

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I've been working on a top-down javascript game for the past few days, and I'm midway through implementing a collision detection system.

I have successfully been able to understand *when* an object hits another, but not which axis (so during movement, I can block that and not the others).

For example. this code works great to detect when the player touches another object, but by checking this it blocks all movement.

```
if(p1x >= topX && p1x <= bottomX 
    && p1y >= topY && p1y <= bottomY)
```

Lets say you hold up and right at the same time. Doing it this method and blocking the movement means that one of those actions that could be perfectly valid are blocked.

[image: Next to bed]

Here for example, if I hold left and up at the same time, all movement is blocked. Unless I only press up or only press right, I will be stuck.

The functionality that I would like to implement would be so that it would only block the movement to the left (on the x axis), while allowing the y axis movement to continue.

I was thinking of checking each axis independently inside each detection of keypress, but would this sacrifice optimisation? (It isn't just doing that one if statement - its also finding the tile and finding the Boundries within there).

Comment: Split out the boundaries and check them all separately, not at the same time with an &&. It will not have a noticeable affect on optimization and would arguably be less computation cycles than the current 4 clause if statement you are using.

Comment: I gave a similar answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911801/tile-map-collide-not-working-as-expected-in-javascript/48926677#48926677 though it's in reference to a tile based system.

You have the right idea, what should work is performing your bounding box to bounding box collision detection for each axis with the current position plus the offset for the axis your checking.

An optimization is not to perform any collision checks if your entity isn't moving.

If it helps I can give you an example of the kind of algorithm I have in mind.